# PowerBI Calculate the Average of a Subgroup of Times

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

this is probably relatively simple, but I've been having some trouble figuring out how to do this.

I have data that looks like this:

```
┌──────┬────────────┬──────┬─────────────┐
│ TAID │ AssignedTo │ Type │ ElapsedTime │
├──────┼────────────┼──────┼─────────────┤
│    1 │ Person1    │ A    │       .0008 │
│    2 │ Person1    │ B    │       .0007 │
│    3 │ Person2    │ A    │       .0005 │
│    4 │ Person3    │ A    │         .05 │
│    5 │ Person2    │ A    │       .0654 │
│    6 │ Person1    │ A    │       .0784 │
│    7 │ Person3    │ B    │       .4567 │
└──────┴────────────┴──────┴─────────────┘
```

I'm supposed to get the average of the elapsed time for each person.

I already have some code that takes the weird PowerBI elapsed time and converts it to HH:mm:ss

```
TaskElapsedTime = 
IF(SUM('qabintaskbin'[ElapsedTime]) >= 1,
    INT(SUM('qabintaskbin'[ElapsedTime]))*24 + 
    INT(FORMAT(SUM('qabintaskbin'[ElapsedTime]),"hh")) & ":" & 
    FORMAT(SUM('qabintaskbin'[ElapsedTime]),"mm:ss")
  ,
    FORMAT(SUM('qabintaskbin'[ElapsedTime]), "hh:mm:ss")
)
```

I was looking into how to break the data down and average it and I found something that suggested this:

```
VAR TheAverage = AVERAGEX(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('qabintaskbin'[AssignedTo])),
    CALCULATE(SUM('qabintaskbin'[ElapsedTime]))
)
```

Combining it with the formatting code becomes:

```
VAR TheAverage = AVERAGEX(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('qabintaskbin'[AssignedTo])),
    CALCULATE(SUM('qabintaskbin'[ElapsedTime]))
)
return IF(TheAverage >= 1,
    INT(TheAverage)*24 + INT(FORMAT(TheAverage,"hh")) & ":" & 
    FORMAT(TheAverage,"mm:ss"),
    FORMAT(TheAverage, "hh:mm:ss")
)
```

But this is just returning the total number it seems?

[image: Test]

I would like it to show the average time spent on individual tasks so like the average of all of `Person1`'s elapsed times in the example would be `.0266`

In writing this out I'm guessing instead of using `AVERAGEX` on the sum of the numbers, I should instead use `DIVIDE` by the `COUNT` of rows or something.

Anyway, if you guys can help me out I'd appreciate it!

Comment: What should the result look like?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the formatting aspect, you should be able to average like this:

```
AvgTime =
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGE ( 'qabintaskbin'[ElapsedTime] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'qabintaskbin', 'qabintaskbin'[AssignedTo] )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - sorry for my slow reply. Unfortunately this is the output I get when I try this (all of them being the same number) https://i.imgur.com/bb8iltq.png What I'm hoping to see is the average I guess based on the number of services they completed. I'm guessing I need to use DIVIDE by some COUNT of rows or something.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work based on your image. You have `User` instead of `AssignedTo` in your table.

Comment: I just renamed the column. User = AssignedTo

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working using this:

```
ElapsedTimeAvgAssignedTo = 
var TheAverage = 
DIVIDE(
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(qabintaskbin[ElapsedTime]),KEEPFILTERS(VALUES(qabintaskbin[AssignedTo]))
  ),
  CALCULATE(
    COUNT(qabintaskbin[AssignedTo]),KEEPFILTERS(VALUES(qabintaskbin[AssignedTo]))
  ),
  ""
)
return IF(TheAverage >= 1,
    INT(TheAverage)*24 + INT(FORMAT(TheAverage,"hh")) & ":" & 
    FORMAT(TheAverage,"mm:ss"),
    FORMAT(TheAverage, "hh:mm:ss")
)
```

Basically divide the sum of the elapsed time filtered by the AssignedTo by the count of those rows to get the average, then convert it to `hh:mm:ss`.

The average time for someone who did two services - one in 7 minutes, one in 13 minutes comes to approximately 10 minutes:

[image: Output]